# Debian can't connect to university Wi-Fi via captive portal

Tags: debian, networkmanager, authentication

Debian 8.5, NetworkManager 0.9.10.0 (stable)

Trying to connect to my university's Wi-Fi (which should be redirecting to a captive portal for authentication steps) doesn't work – clicking on the connection in the NetworkManager menu does not initiate a connection attempt; it simply opens up the Networking menu.

Attempting to connect from the networking menu (via the "play" icon) gets stuck trying to connect.

In case the captive portal is what's causing the problem, I've tried connecting to non-https sites (recommended on the Arch forums) to try to force the captive portal connection, to no avail.

I have no issues connecting to home-style Wi-Fi. Googling around for the problem has proven difficult, as it's either

1. a captive portal problem where none of the common solutions seem to work

   or
2. another problem that I don't know how to describe sufficiently.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I did not solve the issue, but managed to find enough information from my university to manually set up a new Wi-Fi connection which seems to have worked.

Comment: Can you identify the make or provider of the captive portal? (If so, don't forget to [add this information to your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/302881/edit) so everyone can find it easily.

Comment: Captive portals are only applicable once the initial connection is made to their wifi.  If the wifi fails to connect, you should disregard any information about a captive portal which would only be misleading.

Comment: @roaima I only know that it's supposed to redirect to a captive portal from documentation provided by the university - it looks like it might be SecureW2 by JoinNow?

Comment: @JuliePelletier thanks, that's kind of what I was worried about. The only difference between two networks I've recently tried to connect to which haven't worked and others which have, however, is their usage of captive portals. It's confounding.

Comment: Separate out "WiFi" from "Internet access". Can you connect to the WiFi and get an IP address? If not, as Julie Pelletier says, it's pointless talking about a Captive Portal until you've got that part sorted.

Comment: @roaima right, point taken. "WiFi" is correct, as it wasn't even getting to the IP assignment phase.

Comment: What type of security does the connection use?

Comment: @JuliePelletier PEAP, followed by MSCHAPv2 internally.